# How to close the CupertinoActionSheet programatically with BLoC?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm building a 2FA application, which scans a QR code. Then it parses the uri inside QR code and returns a totp code. However, I have a problem closing the CupertinoActionSheet using Navigator.of(context).pop().

I want it to work like that:

1. When a user taps on "add" button, the Action Sheet shows up.
2. When user clicks on "Scan QR code", the Action Sheet must close and then proceed with scanning.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Here's the error that shows ups when I have the code below: "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method."

### Code:

#### home_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:duckie/blocs/manual_input/manual_input_bloc.dart';
import 'package:duckie/blocs/qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner_bloc.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/manual_input/manual_input_screen.dart';
import 'package:duckie/screens/widgets/alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

import 'package:duckie/shared/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'title',
          style: TextStyles.appBarText,
        ).tr(),
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                showAndroidModalBottomSheet(context);
              } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                showIosActionSheet(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<QrCodeScannerBloc, QrCodeScannerState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is QrCodeScannerError) {
            Platform.isAndroid
                ? CustomAlertDialog.showAndroidAlertDialog(context,
                    state.alertDialogErrorTitle, state.alertDialogErrorContent)
                : CustomAlertDialog.showIosAlertDialog(context,
                    state.alertDialogErrorTitle, state.alertDialogErrorContent);
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is QrCodeScannerFinal) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(state.accountName),
                Text(state.issuer),
                Text(state.otp),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showAndroidModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
            title: Text('scan-qr-code').tr(),
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/manual-input');
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
            title: Text('manual-input').tr(),
          ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            leading: Icon(Icons.cancel),
            title: Text('cancel').tr(),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

void showIosActionSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showCupertinoModalPopup(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: Text('action-sheet-title').tr(),
        message: Text('action-sheet-message').tr(),
        actions: [
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.pop(context);

              final String qrCodeResponse =
                  await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
                      '#FF6666', 'cancel'.tr(), true, ScanMode.QR);

              BlocProvider.of<QrCodeScannerBloc>(context).add(
                GetQrCodeResponseEvent(qrCodeResponse),
              );

              // final String uri =
              //     'otpauth://totp/Karol%27s%20Nextcloud%3Aszakes1%40drive.karolzientek.tech?secret=KVZKSQ74SSAVCR27&issuer=Karol%27s%20Nextcloud';
            },
            child: Text('scan-qr-code').tr(),
          ),
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/manual-input');
            },
            child: Text('manual-input').tr(),
          ),
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            isDestructiveAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('cancel').tr(),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem lies within this code fragment:

```
onPressed: () async {
  Navigator.pop(context);

  final String qrCodeResponse =
      await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#FF6666', 'cancel'.tr(), true, ScanMode.QR);

  BlocProvider.of<QrCodeScannerBloc>(context).add(
    GetQrCodeResponseEvent(qrCodeResponse),
  );
  …
},
```

What you're doing is:

1. Popping the CupertinoActionSheet from the Navigation stack.
2. Doing some asynchronous calculations.
3. Using `context` to access the QrCodeScannerBloc.

However, after 1, the `context` (== Element backing CupertinoActionSheet) is no longer active - it got disposed. Using it later is not possible, as it is detached from the tree.

What you can do to avoid this, is to first store the reference to the QrCodeScannerBloc, and use it later, like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  final qrCodeScannerBloc = BlocProvider.of<QrCodeScannerBloc>(context);

  Navigator.pop(context);

  final String qrCodeResponse =
      await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#FF6666', 'cancel'.tr(), true, ScanMode.QR);

  qrCodeScannerBloc.add(GetQrCodeResponseEvent(qrCodeResponse));
  …
},
```